# Can't save Templates in 365 Permssion required even though Full rights

Tags: sharepoint-online, sub-site

I have full admin rights throughout the SharePoint site. I created a simple sub-site which I would like to save as a Template. 'Save as Template' is not an option on the 'Site Settings'. I've disabled the Publishing feature. I have Developer 2013 where the Save to Template button is available and seems to work to a point. The SharePoint site stops with the message 'You don not have access so request'. I then request access and the request comes to me! I approve and try again but get the same result. Any ideas?

Trevor, how do I create a sub-site without Publishing feature active in the first place? Where can I decide which features are enabled or not? Do I need to start the main site again? I've only been working on it a few days so better bad news now. Note I used SharePoint online previously and didn't have this hassle, has something changed in the last year?

Comment: Disabling the Publishing feature is not sufficient. The site must never have the Publishing feature enabled. Saving any site as a template which has or has had the Publishing feature enabled is not supported.